# Rails daily cache block not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

In a ruby on rails 6 app, I want to display a daily quote using a daily cache block. I tried two options:

In controller:

```
@quote_of_the_day = Rails.cache.fetch("daily_quote_#{Date.today}", expires_in: 1.day) do
    Quote.joins(:quote_tags).where(quote_tags: { id: 1 }).order("RANDOM()").limit(1).first
end
```

In the view:

```
<% cache("daily-quote-#{Date.today}", expires_in: 24.hours) do %>
            <blockquote>
                <%= @quote_of_the_day.content.html_safe %>
                <figcaption>
                    <% if @quote_of_the_day.book.present? %>
                        <% if @quote_of_the_day.author.present? %>
                            <%= @quote_of_the_day.author %> — <cite><%= @quote_of_the_day.book %></cite>
                        <% else %>
                            <cite><%= @quote_of_the_day.book %></cite>
                        <% end %>
                    <% elsif @quote_of_the_day.author.present? %>
                        <%= @quote_of_the_day.author %>
                    <% end %>
                </figcaption>
            </blockquote>
        <% end %>
```

It works well in development. But, in production, the quote is updated at each request… You can see it live [on this page](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/citations).

Here is the config/production.rb file:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
default_expiration = 24.hours.to_i
config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: "redis://#{ENV['REDIS_CERES_ADDRESS']}", expires_in: default_expiration }
config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
```

I wonder what I am doing wrong here. The cache with a unique key using the Date.today should be cached and updated every day. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are doing two caching operations- one in the view and one in the controller. Pick one. How is caching configured in production— file? Redis?

Comment: I tried both separately of course. Caching is using Redis in production. I checked the config/production.rb file and the configuration looks good. Also, I use Cloudflare, maybe it affects caching configuration somehow?

Comment: add your configuration to the question

Comment: Thank you, I just added the relevant lines of the config/production.rb file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. About cache options

The better way is using both:

Use `daily_quote_#{Date.today}` as cache key in the controller to avoid querying quote every request:

```rb
@quote_of_the_day = Rails.cache.fetch("daily_quote_#{Date.today}", expires_in: 1.day) do
  xxx
end
```

And use `@quote_of_the_day` as cache key in the view to improve render speed:

```html
<% cache(@quote_of_the_day) do %>
  xxx
<% end %>
```

### 2. About cache is not working

`It works well in development` means cache setting code should be ok;

`the quote is updated at each request` means cache in controller is not working in production.

So the issue may be the Redis config in production.

You could verify if cache and Redis works in production on console:

```rb
# Rails console

# 1. Execute the following code multiple times to see if the result is same
Rails.cache.fetch(Date.today, expires_in: 1.day) { Time.now }

# 2. And try to use Redis directly
redis = Redis.new(url: redis_url)

redis.set(Date.today, Time.now)
redis.get(Date.today)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tested Redis in the console and found out it's not working. Indeed, the ENV['REDIS_CERES_ADDRESS'] was an old address…